# Mail sending problem from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

mail is configured in sql server and it sends mail properly but sometime when i send mail from sql server then i saw the message like "Mail queued." but i dont get the mail. so then i check the mail status by a sp like `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail';`
then i see the mail state is NOTIFIED. then i just stop and start the mail queue using sp called `sysmail_stop_sp` and `sysmail_start_sp`. it is often happening in my sql server mail is getting queued but not sending. i am not being able to catch the problem why often my sql server mail state becomes Notified. please help me that how could get come out from this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTIFIED means the DB Mail process was send an activation message. Until a RECEIVE verb is run on the mail queue, no new notifications will be sent. See [Understanding Queue Monitors](http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/) to understand how this process works.

If your queue remains often in NOTIFIED state it must be that your DB Mail process crashes often. Look into the system event log for clues why this is the case.